# Не получается запустить редактор vim на виртуалке

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, vim, yum

Я установил virtualbox и через него создал виртуальную машину. В ней я работаю с линуксом red hat. Но у меня возникла проблема. Когда я работаю в виртуалке через root мне нужен vim. Я пытался его запустить введя команду vi, но мне пишет, что такая команда не найдена. Потом я подумал, что он значит не установлен, и попытался его установить. Я ввел yum install vim, но выдает ошибку: один из настроенных репозиториев вышел из строя, у yum недостаточно кэшированных данных для продолжения. Такой вопрос: как узнать установлен ли vim, как в таком случае его запустить, а если не установлен, то как установить, и как также запустить? У меня centos 7. Полный текст ошибки: Не удалось получить список зеркал. Не удалось разрешить хост. В одном из настроенных репозиториев произошел сбой, и у yum недостаточно кэшированных данных для продолжения. На данный момент единственная безопасная вещь, которую yum может сделать, это потерпеть неудачу. Если я просто ввожу vi, то выводит: -bash:vi: команда не найдена

Comment: *"один из настроенных репозиториев вышел из строя"* -- приведите полный текст ошибки, добавьте его в вопрос, нажав на [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1447503/edit).

Comment: попробуй команду vim